# Are these sets independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, p)$ be a discrete probability room with induced probability measure $P$ and let $A, B\subseteq \Omega$ be two events.

I want to show that $P((A\cup A^c)\cap B)=P(A)P(B)+P(A^c)P(B)=[P(A)+P(A^c)]P(B)$.

We get that result if $(A\cup A^c)$ and $B$ are independent, or not?

Comment: $(A\cup A^c)\cap B=B$.

Comment: Ah ok! So is $P((A\cup A^c)\cap B)=P(A)P(B)+P(A^c)P(B)=[P(A)+P(A^c)]P(B)$ wrong? @lulu

Comment: It's not wrong, but it is eccentric.  $A\cup A^c$ is all of $\Omega$, so what you wrote is needlessly complex.

Comment: Should say, $(A\cup A^c)\cap B=B$ regardless of whether or not $p(A)$ exists.  Not sure if that is relevant to whatever your situation.

Comment: I actually want to show that $P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)=P(A^c)P(B)-P(A^c\cap B)$. For that I have doneso far: $$$$ We have that $(A\cap B)\cap (A^c\cap B)=\emptyset$ and so $$P((A\cap B)\cup (A^c\cap B))=P(A\cap B)+P (A^c\cap B) \\ \Rightarrow P((A\cup A^c)\cap B)=P(A\cap B)+P (A^c\cap B)$$
Now to get the desired result we have to show that $P((A\cup A^c)\cap B)=P(A)P(B)+P(A^c)P(B)=[P(A)+P(A^c)]P(B)$, or not? $$$$ Or is my approach wrong? @lulu

Comment: Again, it is needlessly complex.  Clearly, $P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)=P(B)$, trusting that all three exist, and $P(A)P(B)+P(A^c)P(B)=P(B)$, with a similar caveat.

Comment: So can we show the desired equality as follows? Since $$P((A\cap B)\cup (A^c\cap B))=P(A\cap B)+P (A^c\cap B) \\ \Rightarrow P((A\cup A^c)\cap B)=P(A\cap B)+P (A^c\cap B)\\ \Rightarrow P( B)=P(A\cap B)+P (A^c\cap B)$$ and since $$P(A)P(B)+P(A^c)P(B)=[P(A)+P(A^c)]P(B)=[P(A)+1-P(A))]P(B)=P(B)$$ (it holds that $P(A^c)=1-P(A)$, right?) then we get $$P(A\cap B)+P (A^c\cap B)=P(A)P(B)+P(A^c)P(B) \Rightarrow P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)=P(A^c)P(B)-P(A^c\cap B)$$ Is that correct? @lulu

Comment: What I already wrote proves it.  Your proposed equality is of the form $x-y=v-w$ and what I wrote shows that $x+w=v+y$.

Comment: All that matters is that $P(E_1)+P(E_2)=P(E_1\cup E_2)$ when $E_1\cap E_2=\emptyset$.  That's all that is going on here.

Comment: But haven't I written that in the way you told in the previous comment? First I prove that $P( B)=P(A\cap B)+P (A^c\cap B)$ then I prove that $P(A)P(B)+P(A^c)P(B)=P(B)$ and so we get the desired result. Or doyou mean something else? @lulu

Comment: $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)$ is obvious, so I don't see the need for all the steps you go through.  But, as I've said, the steps aren't wrong.

Comment: Ok! Thankyou very much!! :-) @lulu